# primitive root of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-logarithms

[Here in the definition of primitive root, it states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Definition): "**a to be a primitive root modulo n, φ(n) has to be the smallest power of a which is congruent to 1 modulo n**" (taking the set of integers)

What my understanding about this statement is that, for any integer $0<a<n$, if it is the primitive root, then, $φ(n)$ has to be the minimum value of $a$ which is congruent to 1 mod n. In particular, **there is no mention that the multiplicative order has to be equal to $φ(n)$**

[But, down here in the examples, it does exactly that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Examples), here, contrary to the definition given, the integer $a$ that does have the multiplicative order of $φ(n)$ is accepted as the primitive root.
Where am I misunderstanding the point?

Comment: "$\phi(n)$ is the smallest power of $a$ which is congruent to $1$ modulo $n$" means that the order of $a$ is $\phi(n)$.  It may be stated a little sloppily, but that's what it means.  It might be clearer to say, "The smallest exponent $m>0$ such that $a^m\equiv1\pmod{n}$ is $\phi(n)$.

Comment: @saulspatz, but in the case of $mod\ 15$, $11^2\ mod15=1$, and $2 < φ()$

Comment: That shows that $11$ is not a primitive root modulo $15$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I meant that k=2 is the smallest positive integer that makes $11^2mod15=1$, so why isn't it the primitive root?

Comment: $\phi(15)=8$, and $2\neq8$, so $11$ is of order not equal to $\phi(15)$ and therefore not a primitive root. Modulo fifteen there are no primitive roots because there are no integers of order eight modulo $15$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, how is (15) the smallest power that is making $a$ congruent to 1????? There are evidently smaller exponents doing the job, I don't get the definition that is being made

Comment: No. $\phi(15)$ is the number of integers $a,0<a<15$, such that $\gcd(a,15)=1$. There are eight of those. See  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) for the definition of $\phi$. The smallest exponent that works *for a given $a$* is called the *order* of $a$ modulo $n$. $\phi(n)$ is simply the number of coprime residue classes modulo $n$, and does not depend on the choice of $a$ at all.

Comment: okay, that remark struck a lightning bolt in my brain. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a$ relatively prime to $n$ we always have,  by Euler's theorem,  that $a^{\varphi (n)}\cong1\pmod n$.

Then for $a$ to be a *primitive root mod n*, $\varphi (n)$ must be the least such value.

That way $a$ generates $C_{\varphi (n)}$.

Comment: I think the symbol you want is \equiv: $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson for some reason I usually use \cong.  I guess because that's the way I seem to remember being taught.

Comment: @ChrisCuster, but in the case of $mod\ 15$, $11^2\ mod15=1$, and $2 < φ()$

Comment: Right.  So $11$ isn't primitive.   I was just about to produce such an example.   You beat me to it.

Comment: $7$ would be primitive.   It is nontrivial to find primitives, in general.

Comment: $7$ is not primitive modulo $15$ as we have $7^4\equiv1\pmod{15}$ but $\phi(15)=8$. Primitive roots exist if and only if $n$ is $2,4$, $p^m$ or $2p^m$ for an odd prime $p$. $\Bbb{Z}_m^*$ is cyclic in those (and only those) cases, and the existence of a primitive root implies cyclicity.

Comment: Oops, I erred.  I checked mod $11$.  Thanks for the catch.  @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: See Jyrki's point:   there is no primitive mod $15$.